# How to fix phpcs, zend standard, for allow arrays to be defined in short syntax []

Tags: php

I have a phpcs error at this line:

```
 return json_encode(['result' => true]);
```

The error of phpcs is this:

```
Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last content on the line
```

How can I fix this ? Is something wrong in syntax? I don't want to use array(..) in place of [].

Comment: Just use proper version. phpcs 1.5 or higher. Check which version corresponds to php language features.

Comment: Thank'you Alma Do. With phpcs 2.0.0(stable) I don't have this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use proper version. phpcs 1.5 or higher. Check which version corresponds to php language features. –